# Identify TreeView Item mouse is over in MouseMove event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I've got a Treeview with a number of items in it. Each item is the part name of a 3D object displayed in another control. I want to be able to move my mouse over the items and identify the item that I am over. This is so I can then pass the item id to the other control where I can highlight the part.

Note that I can already do this with the click event, but I need to do it without any clicking now.

How do I do this in the Mousemove event of the TreeView?

Answer (score 0):

You have the class "System.Windows.Input.Mouse" that could provide you some information like [DirectlyOver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.directlyover(v=vs.110).aspx)

But it could return you the top level of the UIElement so the TreeviewItSelf.

I thinks that another solution might be to test recursively the mouse position relatively to the item.

using [Mouse.GetPosition(UIELEMENT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx) if the position return is negative in one of the coordinate or upper thant the control size that means your are not in the HitTestRectangle of the control.

You could also use [VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243041.aspx) using a rect of size 1 at the relative position about you treeview (Mouse.GetPosition(TREEVIEW)) and you give in second parameter all the treeview itself.